# Change properties of Views in Fragment in Activity with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with two fragments. I am trying to change some views of FragmentOne from FragmentTwo.

In FragmentTwo I have some buttons. When the user clicks on that some Views (like TextViews and ImageViews) should change properties. When the button is clicked in FragmentTwo a Callback is calling the newMessage method in the MainActivity (see code below). In the MainActivity I am trying to change the properties of the Views of FragmentOne, but it does not work.

```
@Override
public void newMessage(String message) {

    View view = viewPager.getChildAt(CALCULATOR_FRAGMENT);

    switch (message){
        case SettingsFragment.CHANGE_COLOR:
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewSum)).setTextColor(Color.RED);
            break;
        case SettingsFragment.NEW_PICTURE:
            ImageSaver imageSaver = new ImageSaver(getBaseContext());

            ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewBackground)).setImageBitmap(imageSaver.load());
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I do not see why it does not work.

Comment: You have to cast the child you obtain from the adapter to your fragment class e.g.: ```FragmentOne fragment = viewPager.getChildAt(CALCULATOR_FRAGMENT);``` And then call a method to update the fragment's UI.
Another way you can use to communicate between your fragments is with EventBus library like Otto, EventBus or RxBus-Android.

Comment: Do FragmentOne and FragmentTwo both have Views with ids textViewSum and imageViewBackground, or does only FragmentOne have them?

Comment: Only FragmentOne does have them.

Answer (score 0):

I create a [demo to show how to update and replace Fragment in ViewPager](https://github.com/li2/Update_Replace_Fragment_In_ViewPager/):

When button clicked in activity, you should update the data, then call `notifyDataSetChanged`,

```
@Override
// page 0 data changed
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    if (id == R.id.main_dayPlusButton) {
        mDate = new Date((mDate.getTime() + 24*3600*1000));
        mViewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

This method will trigger ViewPager Adapter method to be called, you should override `getItemPosition` to update fragment:

```
@Override
// To update fragment in ViewPager, we should override getItemPosition() method,
// in this method, we call the fragment's public updating method.
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    Log.d(TAG, "getItemPosition(" + object.getClass().getSimpleName() + ")");
    if (object instanceof Page0Fragment) {
        ((Page0Fragment) object).updateDate(mDate);
    }
    return super.getItemPosition(object);
};
```

[image]